# Find maximum catches in a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Player Table :

```
Name   Catches  Year
Brady   500      2017
Tom     400      2017
Gyt     350      2017
Brady   600      2018
Tom     660      2018
Gyt     750      2018
```

I want it to return :

```
2017  Brady 
2018  Gyt
```

Explanation: Brady has more catches than anyone in 2017 and Gyt has 750 catches more than anyone in 2018

What I have tried to far :

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(Catches) as TotalCatches, Year 
from Player
Group Name, Year
```

Comment: Does each player have only 1 record per year, or there may be several ?

Comment: @GMB Only one record per year for now

Comment: Which version of sql-server are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using RANK() or RowNumber() like below

```
SELECT p.*
FROM 
(
  SELECT [Year], [Name], Catches, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY[YEAR] ORDER BY [Catches] DESC) RankOf
  FROM Player
) P
WHERE RankOf=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With only one record per player and per year, aggregation is not needed.

You can use a correlated subquery to isolate the top record for each year :

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Player p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Player p1 WHERE p1.year = p.year AND p1.catches > p.catches
)
```

Starting with SQLServer 2017, window functions are the way to go :

```
SELECT year, name, catches 
FROM (
    SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.year ORDER BY p.catches DESC) rn
    FROM Player p
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Player a
WHERE Catches in (
    SELECT max(Catches) FROM Player b WHERE a.year = b.year 
)
```